# Reference a Register in C

Tags: c, linux, pointers

This is from the perspective of someone on a Linux x86 system. Is it possible to store something other than a hardcoded address in a pointer? Here's the catch though: the value going to be stored in the pointer will have previously been stored as a string. Pretty sure there isn't a way for me to reference any register or other pointer but I just wanted to be sure. And I know people are going to ask why I want to do something like this; it would take too long to explain and I'm absolutely sure there is no alternative solution.

Sould have added this:

```
    char* addresses = "\x32\x45\x19..."
```

I want to store something other than a hardcoded address in the "addresses".

EDIT:

lol wow I thought I was fairly clear. I have a array of characters, a pointer, or as I call it: a string. This string is going to be treated as a ZVAL struct in PHP. I am wondering if I can store information other than hardcoded addresses within the string.

Comment: No, not possible without a compiler extension.

Comment: what do you mean by "string" here?

Comment: like char* string = "\x11\x32\..."

Comment: Do you mean like: `char *foo; char *string = "bar"; foo=string;`?

Comment: do you mean "\x11\x32.." is the value of the pointer?

Comment: C does not have a "string" data type. what your have in char * string is just a pointer.

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are trying to do.  You will only get useful answers if you explain what you are trying to achieve.  I'm absolutely sure there is a good solution to your problem. :)

Comment: I have to agree with the other comments.  Your question is totally unclear.  What are you trying to achieve?  Why do you believe you need to store arbitrary stuff in a pointer variable?

Comment: I didn't got what exactly was your requirement.but I can atleast answer one of your question:"Is it possible to store something other than a hardcoded address in a pointer?" answer is YES,you can dynamically allocate memory via malloc and have reference to it in your desired pointer, which I'm sure you must be knowing.So I guess you mean to ask something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the address is stored as a string, you can convert the string to an address (probably via `uintptr_t` defined in `<stdint.h>` or `<inttypes.h>`).  You take the bytes in the string and shift and mask them to produce the integer value equivalent to the address, and then assign the address to the pointer.

```
char *addresses = "\x32...";
char *string = addresses;
uintptr_t value = 0;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(value); i++)
    value = (value << 8) | (*addresses++ & 0xFF);  // Sign extension avoided
void *memory_location = (void *)value;
```

I'm assuming the first byte in the string is the MSB of the address; if (given that you're on Intel) this is wrong (LSB is stored first), you have to adapt the loop to reverse the ordering — one of those infamous 'Exercise for the Reader' observations.

Or you play fast and loose and make the chip do the work.  On RISC platforms (non-Intel), this would lead to a SIGBUS error in general; you might get lucky some of the time, though.

```
char *addresses = "\x32...";
void *memory_location = (void *)(*(uintptr_t *)addresses);
```

This tells the code to treat the `char *` as if it were a `uintptr_t *`, dereference it (reading the whole string at once, except if the address is not properly aligned, it will be two fetches, maybe with a kernel trap in the middle), and assign the value to the memory location.

If your code has any pretense at portability, make sure this is in the 'non-portable code' section.

This is a technical solution to the problem posed (as I understand it); it is not a recommendation that you use it.

Answer (score 0):

you said "lol wow I thought I was fairly clear. I have a array of characters, a pointer, or as I call it: a string. This string is going to be treated as a ZVAL struct in PHP. I am wondering if I can store information other than hardcoded addresses within the string."

Not in the way you do it.

```
 char * addresses = "\x32\x45\x19..." ;
 addresses is set to point to something you should not change.
```

you need to allocate storage for that stuff.

e.g.

```
 char stuff [256] ;
 char * addresses = stuff;
 memcpy(stuff,"\x32\x45\x19...",sizeof("\x32\x45\x19..."));
```